# If class linking happens during run time, why eclipse shows an error during compile time?

Tags: java

I am a java beginner reading the Java 8 spec. In the introduction section, there is a statement : "Run-time activities include loading and linking of the classes needed to execute a program ". If class linking happens during run time time, why does eclipse show an error during compile time if the package name is incorrect because of a typo? Shouldnt it wait till run-time?

Also, Can there be a scenario when a class is not available during compile time. but is available during runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you be more specific about your question. If possible add the code (or similar demo code) along with the error message details.

Comment: This is a conceptual question I got while reading the spec. I have added more details.

Comment: IDE's and compilers can do checks ahead of run time to prevent issues arising during run-time.  For example, you type the name of a class with a typo and it goes and tries to find it (if it does not, it warns you).   Of course, you can edit your whole project in notepad (or a simple text editor) and you will not know you have an issue until compile time.  At that time, the compiler is looking for the mistyped class and will not find it either.  Some exceptions, however, are not as easily checked at compile time, those are the ones seen during run-time (aptly called RunTimeExceptions)

Comment: So, though the linking happens during the runtime, the compiler catches a class name or package name typo and shows it as an error to prevent the linking from failing during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)